# Grab remote form via JS

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I own an affiliate site similar to 8seatercar .com. On it I just installed a SSl.
Basically the car provider embeds a form into my template via JS, which the users fills.

- on step 1 user fills-in the car rental dates
- on step 2 user selects a car
- car on step 3 user confirms the booking with his email address

On step 3 (you can check out the process in the link), I would like to grab the "email" field or the rental dates (since I can identify an order by any), put it in an input/hidden and submit it to myself. I already have all the emails address of the customers, because I speak with them on the phone, and I give them my URL, but without this option it is impossible for me to find out in what booking phase they are, and when they call I do not know if they filled or not the form.

An alternative would be to use my own form and then place manually the booking in the affiliate system, but it is kinda work intensive (manual).

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi Madara,

Yes. On body unload i am calling:

function myFunction() {
var cmail= document.getElementsByName("email").value and passing it to the input hidden and then submitting the form via JS, but it comes blank. 
}

Also it works if I change the last step of the process with my own PHP form, but then i need to "rebook" by hand in the other form.

Ideally I would call my JS on the form submit button or on the onchange in the input email box, but those come as an embed so i cannot actually change them.